# twitter bootstrap, what's wrong with row-fluid inside row-fluid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

in my site, it generates dynamic html, like below

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="row">      
        some html here ..  
    <div>

     some html here

    <form>
       <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
               form elements here ..
```

Is above html is valid one ? can we have `.row-fluid` or `row` inside `row-fluid` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work but I would write the code like this:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="spanX">
        <div class="row">      
            <div class="spanX">
                some html here...
            </div>
        </div>
        some html here
        <form class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                form elements here ..  
            </div>
            <div class="spanY"></div>
        </form>
    </div>
    ...
```

As my experiences suggest, it's better to put `row` or `row-fluid` inside either `container` or `spanX` wrappers.

*X and Y must be a number according to your grid system*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can nest a `.row` or a `.row-fluid` inside a `.row-fluid`. You can find examples in [Bootstrap's documentation](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem).

Comment: but in example it .. shows  `spanX` as inner and then `row(-fluid)`

Comment: Read the 'fluid nesting' section.

Comment: Yes, that's what you'll also have to do. Wrapping a `spanX` around the inner `row (-fluid)` will get you the desired results.

Comment: @rab Oh sorry, I misunderstood what you asked. @adaptive is right, you need to put the inner `.row(-fluid)` inside a `spanX`.
Also, that's the only way it makes sense, doesn't it? You need to specify what part of the outer row the inner row must occupy.